# why the server side recieve null when upload file through https

Tags: java, file-upload, https

I am using https to upload a excel file, this is my server side Java code:

```
@RequestMapping("/dolphin/report/org/user/import")
public interface IOrgUserImportController {


    @PostMapping("/list")
    Response orgUserImport(@RequestBody MultipartFile file);
}
```

now I tried to using postman to test the api, the problem is on the server side, MultipartFile was recieved null. I tried to use Charles to capture the http request(Could not found the request from DevTools), the request look like this:

```
URL https://admin.example.com
Status  Complete
Notes   SSL Proxying not enabled for this host: enable in Proxy Settings, SSL locations
Response Code   200 Connection established
Protocol    HTTP/1.1
TLS TLSv1.2 (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
Method  CONNECT
Kept Alive  No
Content-Type    
Client Address  127.0.0.1:49462
Remote Address  admin.example.com/67.11.108.24:443
Connection  
WebSockets  -
Timing  
Size    
Request 10.03 KB (10,268 bytes)
TLS Handshake   1.29 KB (1,318 bytes)
Header  -
Query String    -
Cookies -
Body    8.74 KB (8,950 bytes)
Uncompressed Body   -
Compression -
Response    26.71 KB (27,353 bytes)
Total   36.74 KB (37,621 bytes)
```

the body was not null, why the server did not recieve the content? what should I do to fix this problem? This is the curl I pasted from postman:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://admin.example.com/service/soa-dolphin-org/service/dolphin/report/org/user/import/list' \
--header 'token: 0e3a2907dfe490eae2c1erea4726c9de7' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' \
--data-binary '@/Users/dolphin/Downloads/Book1.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 0):

We should not use file, just use `Multipart/form-data`:

[image]